# Dúvida com PHP e Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache

Formatei minha máquina e me aconselharam a usar o Linux, e assim o fiz.
Porém no meu `localhost`, os arquivos `.php` não são lidos/reconhecidos, apenas os arquivos `.html`.

Instalei, reinstalei e fiz de tudo que vi pela internet, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: O módulo do php foi configurado no apache? Descreva os procedimentos que executou, tbm deixe os links que consultou.

Comment: Qual é o linux que você está usando e como foi a instalação? Você seguiu algum tutorial específico?

Comment: O problema está na configuração do seu servidor, pois se o php não está rodando, é porque você não configurou corretamente. Não tem como prevê o que você fez e tem para poder ajudar. Eu voto para que sua pergunta seja fechada.

Comment: Eu instalei instalei o lamp, vi um procedimento pela internet, acredito que seja basicamente o mesmo procedimento, meio que segui esse tutorial (http://blog.wfsneto.com.br/2011/12/17/config-como-configurar-ambiente-desenvolvimento-php-no-ubuntu-11-10).

Comment: No terminal usei um $ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enable/000-default.conf e alterei a pasta do apache. E criei um arquivo php.info pelo terminal e funcionou. porém quando eu crio outro arquivo pelo Sublime por exemplo.. não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi. O meu problema era com permissões, dei um "$ sudo chmod 777 /var/www" no terminal e funcionou!

Comment: Se você resolveu, marque sua própria resposta como a solução

Answer (score 5):

Aconselho a seguir um tutorial para configuração do PHP, Apache e MySQL (se quiser) no linux. Tem [este tutorial da Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-a-pilha-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-no-ubuntu-14-04-pt), que sempre utilizo quando preciso.

Answer (score 3):

Se estiver utilizando Ubuntu ou derivado você poderia utilizar o comando a baixo aonde deixa seu lamp 100% funcional:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Comment: eu já havia instalado o lamp

Comment: @Albi Lamp não é a aplicação lamp e sim quer dizer Linux Apache Mysql Php (aka LAMP), ele instala cada um em separado e faz toda a integração deles facilita muito.

Comment: Sim, eu havia visto esse termo e fui ver o que significava. Eu quis dizer que eu fiz o "procedimento".

Comment: é que existe uma aplicação LAMP https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp um pacote completo nada mais porem usando o comando que passei é mais pratico e mais otimizado. @Albi